# Does Sonarqube 6.0 support svn scm through webdav (http/https) protocol?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Does sonarqube 6.0 support retrieval of scm blame info from a svn server through webdav (http/https) protocol? In the docs I only see references to svn or svn+ssh protocols.

If so, how to configure?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, retrieval of blame information through wedav protocol is not supported.

Comment: Humm, I see. In order to avoid the installation of svnserve, can SQ be configured for direct svn file: access? (both subversion and sonarqube are installed in the same machine)